# Should the home page canonical URL end in a "/" or does it matter?

Tags: canonical-link

For the home page's canonical URL...

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://mysite.com" />
```

OR

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://mysite.com/" />
```

AND

Where should it be placed within the head section? at the top, somewhere in the middle, or last?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The rel="canonical" attribute should be used only to specify the preferred
version of many pages with identical content (although minor differences,
such as sort order, are okay).
```

That's from the Google description of the `canonical` link. Therefore you shouldn't be using the site's root, therefore this question is moot.

Comment: For my home page, I assign a single post to be the "home" page. Therefore, I have two URLs that go to the same page, www.site.com and www.site.com/single-post-title. So I'm trying to tell search agents which URL to index for both these pages. But the question is, slash or no slash?

Comment: In that case, slash. That way you are referencing the index file of the root, rather than the root itself.

Comment: Its not moot, you might have a duplicate home page under a trailing /index.html, so then you would want a canonical on that page, which would then be on the root.

Answer (score 0):

Should it?  I don't think there's a single answer to that.  Does it matter?  Yes, in many cases.  It's two different URLs, and there can be cases (such as with web optimizationn or analytics) when code is looking at the URL and making decisions on what it contains.  If it expects "www.mysite.com/page?test=1" and sees "www.mysite.com/page/?test=1" it won't work.  Server redirects may also be affected by the difference.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not asking about inside pages, I'm only asking about the home page and whether a trailing slash is required, preferred or irrelevant.  example.com, example.com/, www.example.com and www.example.com/ are all see as different URLs by google.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't already have a redirect to force a trailing /, then you can choose to use either version of the canonical tag.

Its up to you, how would you like your url to appear in the search results, with a trailing / or without?

You may place the canonical tag any where in the head section.

Answer (score 0):

I come also recently to decide my canonical url of my homepage whether use trailing slash or not. Googling to the case could not find a good answer. However I marked that top searching are mostly resulting to site homepage with trailing slash.